# Work done by a homogeneous gravitational field on a system of particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, work

Perhaps this is trivial: how does one prove that the work done by a homogeneous gravitational field on a system of particles is equal to the work done on a point mass with the total mass of the system, located at the center of mass of the system.

Comment: The Shell Theorem proves it for spheres: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem
I don't think it's true for non-spherical bodies as I'm pretty sure you could get a torque as part of the attraction.

Comment: Gravity is a central force. A consequence of this is that it will not exert a net external torque on a system by its own self.

Answer (score 1):

The total work done by gravity is
$$W = \sum_{i=1}^N \int m_i\mathbf v_i\cdot\mathbf g\text dt.$$
Commuting sum and integral one gets
$$W = \int\left(\sum_{i=1}^N m_i\mathbf v_i\right)\cdot\mathbf g\text dt.$$
The quantity inside the parentheses is precisely $M\mathbf v_{\text{CoM}}$, so
$$W = M\int\mathbf v_{\text{CoM}}\cdot\mathbf g\text dt,$$
which looks like the work done by a particle of mass $M$ moving as the centre of mass of the particles at $\mathbf r_i$